# Apache Commons DiffBuilder, deep compare

Tags: java, apache, compare, diff

We try to use Appache commons `DiffBuilder` and also `ReflectionDiffBuilder` in version 3.7` to compare two complex objects each other.

For a simple object it is working really good, but I'm not able to get it work with properties which are an List of other Complex Objects which could contain again a complex object.

Let me explain better, if we have for Example this object (we will represent it for simplicity by an json object):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Master1",
    "details": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Master1.Detail1"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Master2.Detail2",
        "subDetail": [{
            "id1": 1,
            "name": "Master2.Detail2.SubDetail1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

In This Case if we change `name` in `SubDetail1` and compare old with new object we need also to be notified that the property in the third level of 3 complex objects changed.

Is this possible with Apaches library? It seems not out of the box?

Answer (score -1):

In your parent diff method you should iterate through your collections and compare each sub entities and append all differences in your parent diff result object.